# Proftpd: total disable user login

Tags: proftpd

A simple question,with this configuration I allow anon ftp users.

```
ServerName          "ProFTPD Default Installation"
ServerType          standalone
DefaultServer           on
Port                2121
Umask               022
MaxInstances            30
User                ftp
Group               ftp
SystemLog           /var/log/proftpd.log
TransferLog         /var/log/xferlog
PassivePorts 49152 65535
UseFtpUsers off
<Directory /*>
  AllowOverwrite        on
</Directory>
  <Limit LOGIN>
    AllowUser ftp
    AllowUser anonymous
    DenyAll
  </Limit>
<Anonymous ~ftp>
  RequireValidShell     off
  User              ftp
  Group             ftp
  # We want clients to be able to login with "anonymous" as well as "ftp"
  UserAlias         anonymous ftp
  # Limit the maximum number of anonymous logins
  MaxClients            50
  # We want 'welcome.msg' displayed at login, and '.message' displayed
  # in each newly chdired directory.
  DisplayLogin          welcome.msg
  DisplayChdir          .message
  # Limit WRITE everywhere in the anonymous chroot
  <Limit WRITE>
    DenyAll
  </Limit>
  # An upload directory that allows storing files but not retrieving
  # or creating directories.
</Anonymous>
```

But using

```
ftp localhost 21
```

It ask for password
My question is: how to disable totally the user login to allow only anonymous?
I want an answer like this

```
"sorry ftp server is only anonymous"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from [ProFTPD: Configuring Limits](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Limit.html)

> What if a site wished to allow only anonymous access? This would be configured using the LOGIN command group, as above:

```
<Limit LOGIN>
  DenyAll
</Limit>

<Anonymous ~ftp>
  <Limit LOGIN>
    AllowAll
  </Limit>
  ...
</Anonymous>
```

> The `<Limit>` section outside of the `<Anonymous>` section denies logins to everyone. However, the `<Anonymous>` section has a `<Limit>` that allows everyone to login; anonymous logins are allowed, and non-anonymous logins are denied.

P.S. You may want to create separate `DisplayLogin sorry.msg` outside `<Anonymous>` section with "sorry ftp server is only anonymous" text in sorry.msg file.